# Plot into Pycharm's IPython console

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, pycharm

I'm using spyder and pycharm for python coding. When I plot something with matplotlib in spyder it shows the result inline in IPython.
With Pycharm IPython plots in a new extra window.
I'm working on Windows7 and with Anaconda Python2.7.

Is it possible to plot in Pycharm inside in the IPython shell?

Comment: Try running `%matplotlib inline` before you start plotting.

Comment: In Community Edition 2020, the answer is no. The answers about Jupyter support only apply to PyCharm [Professional Edition](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/scientific-tools.html), as Jupyter support [was removed from CE2019](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360003364739-Jupyter-in-Community-Edition-PyCharm-Reasons-not-to-upgrade-to-2019).  Also, `%matplotlib inline` in the console gives:
`IPython.core.error.UsageError: Invalid GUI request 'inline', valid ones are:dict_keys(['none', 'osx', 'tk', 'gtk', 'wx', 'qt', 'qt4', 'qt5', 'glut', 'pyglet', 'gtk3'])`.

Answer (score 5):

Not inside the shell; however, you can use an iPython notebook within PyCharm (2016+) for that purpose. PyCharm supports iPython plots when defined within a `.ipynb` (iPython/Jupyter file format) script.

Here is an example:
Open, or create (as shown) a `.ipynb` script:

[image]

An here is what you get if you code inside a freshly made `.ipynb` file within PyCharm 2016 or later. Notice the `%matplotlib inline`, which comes after `matplotlib.pyplot` import.

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to make plots interactive in this way without creating a separate window?

Answer (score 2):

#### PyCharm 2019.1+

In this version of PyCharm several [great features](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/whatsnew/#v2019-1-jupyter-notebooks) to integrate Jupyter Notebooks and PyCharm were added.

First, create a new Jupyter Notebook or open up an existing one.

Second, you can Insert a new cell or you can work on existing cells.

[image]

Third, you can Run or Debug a Cell:

[image]

Fourth, if you run the cell, the result will be reflected in the right side of the screen.

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to further analyse the figure (ie, zoom, save, etc.), in a similar way to VSCode?

Comment: ^ This is the key feature missing, VSCode has an edge here

Comment: Add `%matplotlib qt` after `%matplotlib inline` and press run all. The plots will open in a new window which can be resized, moved, zoomed and the plot can be saved as a file