# Pycharm show matplotlib graph inline

Tags: matplotlib, pycharm

I have searched this for long time, similar questions have been asked but none solved my problem.

Usually I run my py files by `ctrl+shift+r`, and what I expect is to show the graphs in side the session, like the way it works for Jupyter notebook. But instead it either omits the graph, or show it separately and if I have several graphs they will all pop once and lock the session.

Something like `%matplotlib inline` but for default python files.

So far I have tried to add the `env var` for Pycharm, and tried to play around with `plt.isinterative`, nothing worked :(

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for. Would it solve your problem if you ran Jupyter with Pycharm? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-ipython-jupyter-notebook-with-pycharm.html

Comment: @Jerry101 thank you for the reply. I know we can create a Jupyter like env for Pycharm, but I want to keep it as usual python environment but show the graphs inside the built in running session window, the one get popped if you press `Run` or `ctrl+R`

Comment: Pycharm has a Scientific Mode which can plots in the console. I'll have to try this! https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/scientific-mode-support.html

Comment: @Jerry101I will check it out too, that looks hopeful!

Comment: @Jerry101 I got it working! Thank you sooo much!

Comment: This may be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30816028/plot-into-pycharms-ipython-console.  tl;dr: After the previous comments were posted, scientific mode was removed from the free version - it's only in Professional Edition.