# Plot function during pytest debugging in console mode

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm, pytest

I am writing a unit test for a scientific function and when I was trying to check its shape
I obtained an error with `matplotlib`.

I am using PyCharm Community Edition 2022.3.3, python 3.11, matplotlib 3.7.1 and PySide6 6.5.0 under Windows 10.

When debugging the test, I was trying to plot the function in console mode and I obtained this error/warning and no plot:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.3.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_exec2.py", line 3, in Exec
    exec(exp, global_vars, local_vars)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\devot\Work\PythonEnvs\science_env\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2812, in plot
    return gca().plot(
           ^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\devot\Work\PythonEnvs\science_env\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2309, in gca
    return gcf().gca()
           ^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\devot\Work\PythonEnvs\science_env\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 906, in gcf
    return figure()
           ^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\devot\Work\PythonEnvs\science_env\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\_api\deprecation.py", line 454, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\devot\Work\PythonEnvs\science_env\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 840, in figure
    manager = new_figure_manager(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\devot\Work\PythonEnvs\science_env\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 384, in new_figure_manager
    return _get_backend_mod().new_figure_manager(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\devot\Work\PythonEnvs\science_env\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 3574, in new_figure_manager
    return cls.new_figure_manager_given_figure(num, fig)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\devot\Work\PythonEnvs\science_env\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 3579, in new_figure_manager_given_figure
    return cls.FigureCanvas.new_manager(figure, num)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\devot\Work\PythonEnvs\science_env\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 1742, in new_manager
    return cls.manager_class.create_with_canvas(cls, figure, num)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\devot\Work\PythonEnvs\science_env\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 2858, in create_with_canvas
    return cls(canvas_class(figure), num)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\devot\Work\PythonEnvs\science_env\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt.py", line 204, in __init__
    _create_qApp()
  File "C:\Users\devot\Work\PythonEnvs\science_env\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt.py", line 134, in _create_qApp
    QtWidgets.QApplication.setAttribute(
DeprecationWarning: Enum value 'Qt::ApplicationAttribute.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling' is marked as deprecated, please check the documentation for more information.
```

If I run the code not as a test everything is fine.

These are a working example to obtain the error:

```
# test_scientific_functions.py

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def test_sin():
    x = np.arange(0, 25, 0.1)
    y = np.sin(x)
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.show()
```

This code generates this message:

```
test\unit\test_scientific_functions.py:22 (test_sin)
def test_sin():
        x = np.arange(0, 25, 0.1)
        y = np.sin(x)
>       plt.plot(x, y)

test\unit\test_scientific_functions.py:26: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
..\..\PythonEnvs\science_env\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py:2812: in plot
    return gca().plot(
..\..\PythonEnvs\science_env\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py:2309: in gca
    return gcf().gca()
..\..\PythonEnvs\science_env\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py:906: in gcf
    return figure()
..\..\PythonEnvs\science_env\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\_api\deprecation.py:454: in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
..\..\PythonEnvs\science_env\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py:840: in figure
    manager = new_figure_manager(
..\..\PythonEnvs\science_env\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py:384: in new_figure_manager
    return _get_backend_mod().new_figure_manager(*args, **kwargs)
..\..\PythonEnvs\science_env\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py:3574: in new_figure_manager
    return cls.new_figure_manager_given_figure(num, fig)
..\..\PythonEnvs\science_env\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py:3579: in new_figure_manager_given_figure
    return cls.FigureCanvas.new_manager(figure, num)
..\..\PythonEnvs\science_env\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py:1742: in new_manager
    return cls.manager_class.create_with_canvas(cls, figure, num)
..\..\PythonEnvs\science_env\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py:2858: in create_with_canvas
    return cls(canvas_class(figure), num)
..\..\PythonEnvs\science_env\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt.py:204: in __init__
    _create_qApp()
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

    @functools.lru_cache(1)
    def _create_qApp():
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
    
        # Create a new QApplication and configure it if none exists yet, as only
        # one QApplication can exist at a time.
        if app is None:
            # display_is_valid returns False only if on Linux and neither X11
            # nor Wayland display can be opened.
            if not mpl._c_internal_utils.display_is_valid():
                raise RuntimeError('Invalid DISPLAY variable')
    
            # Check to make sure a QApplication from a different major version
            # of Qt is not instantiated in the process
            if QT_API in {'PyQt6', 'PySide6'}:
                other_bindings = ('PyQt5', 'PySide2')
            elif QT_API in {'PyQt5', 'PySide2'}:
                other_bindings = ('PyQt6', 'PySide6')
            else:
                raise RuntimeError("Should never be here")
    
            for binding in other_bindings:
                mod = sys.modules.get(f'{binding}.QtWidgets')
                if mod is not None and mod.QApplication.instance() is not None:
                    other_core = sys.modules.get(f'{binding}.QtCore')
                    _api.warn_external(
                        f'Matplotlib is using {QT_API} which wraps '
                        f'{QtCore.qVersion()} however an instantiated '
                        f'QApplication from {binding} which wraps '
                        f'{other_core.qVersion()} exists.  Mixing Qt major '
                        'versions may not work as expected.'
                    )
                    break
            try:
>               QtWidgets.QApplication.setAttribute(
                    QtCore.Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling)
E                   DeprecationWarning: Enum value 'Qt::ApplicationAttribute.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling' is marked as deprecated, please check the documentation for more information.

..\..\PythonEnvs\science_env\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt.py:134: DeprecationWarning
```

If I run this other code everything is fine:

```
# plot.py

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def plot_sin():
    x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.1)
    y = np.sin(x)

    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    plot_sin()
```

Do it mean that, in some way, `pytest` goes into conflict with `matplotlib.pyplot`?

Do you have any advice?

Comment: What happens if you switch to plotting inline with scientific mode? **DeprecationWarning: Enum value 'Qt::ApplicationAttribute.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling' is marked as deprecated, please check the documentation for more information.** is a warning.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney I don't know how to do it, could you tell me please? thanks

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/matplotlib-support.html

Comment: this is a function available only in PyCharm Professional, I have the Community Edition

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/q/24886625/7758804 has options to try. Like `matplotlib.use('TkAgg')`, and https://stackoverflow.com/q/30816028/7758804

Comment: Thanks @TrentonMcKinney adding the backend works, even if I thought it was not necessary with `pyplot`. `TkAgg` works fine, if I use `QtAgg` it gives the same warning and no plot. I have to think better about the future GUI...

Comment: Also see [matplotlib: Backends](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/backends.html)